# How to use a vapor api in a swift iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, api, vapor

I am trying to figure out how to use my vapor api. What i have seen online and everywhere is mostly creating a website using vapor, but what i haven't been able to see is how to use an api i built with an app i am building. what I want to do is create a mobile app that uses a vapor api that i built myself. I have the api, the problem that i am having is creating the iOS swift app to go along with it. 
I have seen all the example api and swift apps that vapor has on their GitHub, but they are very confusing to understand for me because they have probably 100 controllers and models. I have been creating practice vapor api, and i know they work because i have been testing them on postman, it is just that next step that is confusing me.

If it helps, here is a hypothetical. If I have a simple test api that is using a mysql database that has database that has an id number, names of famous celebrities, and famous quotes they have said. I want to create a swift iOS app that is just a tableview that shows all the celebrity names that i have on my database and when that name is pressed a list of all the quotes appears.

I am sorry for being very repetitive, but i just wanted to be as clear as possible. If i may ask, please be specific with the help, and thank you for all your help.

Comment: To clarify: your Vapor app is complete and serves an API which does what you want; but you now need your iOS app to consume that API?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your iOS does exactly the same as Postman - it's just a different client. You can use `URLSession` or Alamofire to make requests to your API as you have been doing in Postman to consume that API.

Comment: thank you for the help. If i may ask a question in regards to this? I tried to use URLSession but for some reason it says that there is no JSON. I also heard Alamofire is slower then the using URLSession. What would be a method you would use in this situation? Also i noticed that using urlsession and alamo fire usually  use https: instead of http: that vapor creates. Is that important? Also is the url that i use the localhost i use for postman? thank you

Comment: I think the difference between Alamofire and URLSession is negligible on device, but stick with what you know. Where does the no JSON come from? If it's on the Vapor side, make sure you are setting the `content-type` header in the request.
When you deploy you should have HTTPS enabled, but for development HTTP is fine. The URL to use when running the iOS application on device will be your server IP address instead of localhost, probably something like 192.168.0.10 for a local network